# Delegating a dynamic finder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've got some models that represents different kinds of points a user can earn:

```
class User
  has_many :totals
end

class Total
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :total_type
end

class TotalType
  has_many :totals
end
```

And there are named types like `points` and `goals`. I added a nice `method_missing` to Total:

```
def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
  if TotalType.find_by_name(method)
    joins(:total_type).where(:total_type => { :name => method }).sum(total)
  else
    super
  end
end
```

And that lets me do some sweet dynamic stuff like:

```
user = User.first
user.totals.points #=> 100
user.totals.goals  #=> 10
```

Now the hard part. I want to be able to call those same `points` and `goals` method on User directly. If I use `delegate` then I need to know the name of the methods ahead of time:

```
class User
  # ...
  delegate :points, :totals, :to => :totals
end
```

But of course I'd prefer that was dynamic as well. I tried creating a `method_missing` on User but when I try to `send` something to `totals` I get `NoMethodError: undefined method 'points' for #<Array:0x007fd2016e1510>` so apparently the association proxy has already transformed the result set into an array (`super` left out to keep the example simple):

```
class User
  #...
  def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
    totals.send(method, *args, &block)
  end
end  

user = User.first
user.totals.points  #=> 100
user.points  #=> NoMethodError: undefined method 'points' for #<Array:0x007fd2016e1510>
```

How can I forward this call onto `totals` without having to hardcode those dynamic finder names? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What about using a named scope instead?

Comment: But I'd have to give the scope a hardcoded name like 'points' or 'goals'...I really want those to be dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, using a named_scope (or class method) is your best bet.

For example, if this is totals.rb:

```
class Total < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :total_type

  def self.points
    joins(:total_type).where(:total_types => {:name => 'points'}).sum(:total)
  end
end
```

and this is users.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :totals

  def method_missing(name, *args, &blk)
    if totals.respond_to? name
      totals.send(name, *args, &blk)
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

then User.first.points #=> 100

You could make this even more dynamic... but the code is harder to follow and if you don't cache some stuff then a lot of unnecessary SQL queries are being performed. For example, total.rb could be like this:

```
class Total < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :total_type

  def self.method_missing(name, *args, &blk)
    if TotalType.find_by_name(name.to_s)
      joins(:total_type).where(:total_types => {:name => name.to_s}).sum(:total)
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def self.respond_to_missing?(name, priv)
    if TotalType.find_by_name(name.to_s)
      true
    else
      super
    end
  end

end
```

So when User.first.points gets called, first User#method_missing gets called, which sees if user.totals.respond_to? :points. It doesn't at first, so Total::respond_to_missing gets called, which sees if there's a total_type called 'points'. There is... so it's called and then Total::method_missing is called, which gives you back the sum of points for that user.

Of course you could easily cache results so the unnecessary SQL queries aren't performed every time user.points is called in the method_missing and respond_to_missing methods, but it just gets too complicated and the method overhead isn't worth it. The less dynamic solution I offered earlier is your best bet with how your models are laid out now.

Hope this helps,

-Luke

Comment: But you had to hardcode the name of the method in Total (def self.points)...I want those to all be dynamic so as new types are created in the database they're ready to be used in the code.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I gave the second example for the more dynamic way.

Answer (score 0):

If dynamics are your concern, a named scope like `by_total_type` might solve the problem.

```
class Total

  scope :by_total_type, lambda { |ttype| joins(:total_type).where(:type => ttype) }

end
```

Then you can say:

```
Total.by_total_type('point')
```

Or

```
user.totals.by_total_type('goal')
```

Comment: But that's no fun, I want the syntax of user.totals.points (which already works with my original method_missing) and user.points and then as new point types are added to the database they just become available to call on the models without hardcoding any method names anywhere: user.goals, user.rebounds, user.assists, etc.